# Invalid column name AgtTableId

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to change the schema of a particular table via a `T-SQL` script. I want to create a temporary table, dump the relevant data into that table, drop/re-create the original table and then transfer the data.

The script seems to work fine as long as I don't run the final `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO AgentRelationshipCodes(RelationshipId, EffectiveDate, LastChangeDate, LastChangeId, AgtTableId)
SELECT RelationshipId, EffectiveDate, LastChangeDate, LastChangeId, ID 
FROM tmpAgentRelationshipCodes
```

At that point I get the error message

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Invalid column name 'AgtTableId'.
```

Not sure why, though, as I'm clearly creating this field in the first `CREATE TABLE` statement. Also, if I run the rest of the script (basically create two tables, dump the data into the temporary table) and the `INSERT` statement separately they will work.

```
CREATE TABLE tmpAgentRelationshipCodes
(
ID int,
RelationshipId char(3),
EffectiveDate datetime,
LastChangeDate datetime,
LastChangeId char(6)
);

INSERT INTO tmpAgentRelationshipCodes(ID, RelationshipId, EffectiveDate, LastChangeDate, LastChangeId)
SELECT ID, RelationshipId, EffectiveDate, LastChangeDate, LastChangeId
FROM AgentRelationshipCodes

DROP TABLE AgentRelationshipCodes

CREATE TABLE AgentRelationshipCodes
(
Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID(),
RelationshipId char(3) NULL,
EffectiveDate datetime NULL,
LastChangeDate datetime NOT NULL,
LastChangeId char(6) NOT NULL,
AgtTableId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AgentTransmission(ID)
);

INSERT INTO AgentRelationshipCodes(RelationshipId, EffectiveDate, LastChangeDate, LastChangeId, AgtTableId)
SELECT RelationshipId, EffectiveDate, LastChangeDate, LastChangeId, ID 
FROM tmpAgentRelationshipCodes
```

Comment: This looks like a parser error occurring within SSMS, right? (a) use the `dbo.` prefix on all objects (it could be conflicting with a similar table under another schema) and (b) put a `GO` between the `CREATE` and the `INSERT`.

Comment: worked perfectly. If you want to add as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

Edited the script as follows to include [dbo] and also needed the `GO` statements to separate commands.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tmpAgentRelationshipCodes]
(
ID int,
RelationshipId char(3),
EffectiveDate datetime,
LastChangeDate datetime,
LastChangeId char(6)
);
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tmpAgentRelationshipCodes](ID, RelationshipId, EffectiveDate, LastChangeDate, LastChangeId)
SELECT ID, RelationshipId, EffectiveDate, LastChangeDate, LastChangeId
FROM [dbo].[AgentRelationshipCodes]
GO

DROP TABLE [dbo].[AgentRelationshipCodes]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AgentRelationshipCodes]
(
Id int PRIMARY KEY,
RelationshipId char(3) NULL,
EffectiveDate datetime NULL,
LastChangeDate datetime NOT NULL,
LastChangeId char(6) NOT NULL,
AgtTableId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AgentTransmission(ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[AgentRelationshipCodes](RelationshipId, EffectiveDate, LastChangeDate, LastChangeId, AgtTableId)
SELECT RelationshipId, EffectiveDate, LastChangeDate, LastChangeId, ID 
FROM [dbo].[tmpAgentRelationshipCodes]
```